# including Qt headers in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: qt, header

I faced with problem, which is very hard for me to cope with. I have searched all possible sites and tried a lot of actions and spent almost 10 hours but problem remained.

Problem description:

I use visual studio 2010. I Installed Qt library: Qt libraries 4.8.1 for Windows (VS 2010, 235 MB) also installed Qt visual studio add in.
I remember I typed something in cmd line (to include envoirement variables), text was given in stack overflow(now I lost link to that theme and can't find it).
So I set up Qt library and it worked. Accidentially I installed visual studio 2008, and problems begun.
Previously I was able to include Qt headers like:

```
#include <QtCore>
#include <QtGui>
```

but now I have to specify full path like

```
#include<QtCore\...>
```

and QtCore is shown as folder, which wasn't before. It is very unconvinient for me.

So please advice me, that to do to solve this problem (no need to specify full path to the Qt headers).
I will be very appreciated!

Comment: More insight in my situation:

Comment: OS: Windows 7. Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate.                           I Download Qt-win-opensource-4.8.1 -vs 2010.exe(http://qt.nokia.com/downloads/windows-cpp-vs2010) . I install it. I got C:\Qt\4.8.1 directory. When I installed qt-vs-addin-1.1.10. When I ran Qt by Nokia(VS2010 OpenSource)\visual studio with Qt 4.8.1 (Which was created after installation of add-in) and got information that envoirement varibales were configured (PATH was set, QDIR was set) but when I checked this by : computer/advances properties/ envoirement varibales no changes were made.

Comment: Also to mention I deleted all programs related to Visual Studio 2008(using control panel), and uninstalled and installed 2010, but it haven`t sorted situation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to add a few more directories to your include dirs

```
$(QTDIR)\include
$(QTDIR)\include\QtGui
$(QTDIR)\include\Qtcore
$(QTDIR)\include\QtOpenGL
```

But not oddly `$(QTDIR)\include\Qt`! If you get a warning about direct includes check you don't have `include\Qt` on the list

If you create the project with VS2010 add-in it will add these directories for you

---

edit: The comments are getting a bit long so I will try and explain.

The top level `$(QTDIR)\include` doesn't have any include files (.h) but is necessary so the other includes can use paths relative to this eg `#include <QtCore/QtCore>`

Qt for reason best known to themselves (but probably due to long winter nights and consumption of Aquavit) use an include file with no .h extention as the master include file for a module and then put it in a directory with the same name.

So you add `$(QTDIR)\include\QtGui` to the list of include paths and then `#include <GtGui>` from within it, this will in turn load all the 100s of individual .h files for all the gui functions.

The fact that the file and directory have the same name is ignored by the pre-processor - it knows not to try and include directories.

hint: See [Visual studio intellisense for headers without .h](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210247/visual-studio-intellisense-for-headers-without-h) for dealing with the headers and intellisense

Comment: How to add these directories? So, that changes you made  would be applicable for all created projects. It`s very time consuming to specify include directories for every project you create.

Comment: I normally just use the vc-directories tab in project settings. VS2010 screwed up the global settings with their new system, see http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vcgeneral/thread/a494abb8-3561-4ebe-9eb0-6f644a679862 for hints

Comment: I have included DIRs you recommended, but situation remained the same, as from where I started: still need to specify full path to header files. May be I need to include some environment variables (my computer advanced options/ env var) although I have included QTDIR and QTDIR\bin(in path) but this took no effect

Comment: It works!!! So, I can #include <GtGUI>, but by strange way: when i type in file #include <QtGui , QtGui appears as folder, and i have to specify full route, but if instead i press space then del and then > - I got #include <QtGUI> which compiles fine and works great. Maybe i need to change other settings in VS to be able to include directly QtGui, if so, what settings should i change??

Comment: I think it is IntelliSense problem, so I wonder, how to configure it that it will pass statements such as #include <QtGui>. Also thanks a lot for hint about setting vc directories!!

Comment: Thank you very much for detailed explanations and help, which was very usefull for me and I think saved a lot of time.

Comment: Problem with including Qt headers in VS 2010 no longer exists for me!

Answer (score 1):

You may find [this walkthrough](http://eecs.vanderbilt.edu/research/hmtl/wiki/pmwiki.php?n=Knowledge.Qt) concerning installing Qt from source pretty helpful. It's the way I've been installing Qt with Visual Studio for years and I've never had any problems, including the one you mention.

Are you using qmake to generate your .sln? Perhaps you could give a little more insight as to your install process and maybe I (or someone else) can offer more help.

Also, I personally find [QtWizard2010](http://www.sanfordfreedman.com/utilities/) a very straightforward and well integrated way of generating Qt projects within Visual Studio. Perhaps it may help here.

Comment: I downloaded Qt version already compiled for Visual Studio 2010, do I need to built it ??? That is why I don`t think aricle you adivised suits me. To generate sln I use nmake as I have VS 2010 Ultimate.